# Masking parts of URL rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am fairly new to rails and currently looking to find a way to mask the URL's so that they are more readable.

Currently I have jobs as a nested resource of users and so my URL's are showing as:

`localhost:3000/users/1/jobs/8`

I would like to have the URL show as something simple like:

`localhost:3000/jobs/8`

It would be great to know how I can integrate this into my routes to have more readable URL's.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: did you look into your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`resources`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) method has a `shallow` option:

> This allows URLs for resources that otherwise would be deeply nested such as a comment on a blog post like `/posts/a-long-permalink/comments/1234` to be shortened to just `/comments/1234`.

Example:

```
resources :users, :shallow => true do
  resources :jobs
end
```

This gives you:

```
   user_jobs GET    /users/:user_id/jobs(.:format)     jobs#index
             POST   /users/:user_id/jobs(.:format)     jobs#create
new_user_job GET    /users/:user_id/jobs/new(.:format) jobs#new
    edit_job GET    /jobs/:id/edit(.:format)           jobs#edit
         job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)                jobs#show
             PUT    /jobs/:id(.:format)                jobs#update
             DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)                jobs#destroy
```